# Why is the background color of my HTML element not changing in JavaScript when the conditions are met

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the background color of a wrapper div depending on the value of the counter so if positive I am changing the background to green and if its negative I'm giving red color and if not any it is dark blue. here is my code below.

```js
let counter = 0;
let counterWrapper = document.querySelector('.counter');
let btnIncrease = document.getElementById('btn-increase');
let btnDecrease = document.getElementById('btn-decrease');
let counterValue = document.getElementById('counter-value');
let bgColor = counterWrapper.style.backgroundColor;


btnIncrease.addEventListener('click', function(){
    counter++;
    counterValue.textContent = counter;
    changeColor();
});

btnDecrease.addEventListener('click', function(){
    counter--;
    counterValue.textContent = counter;
    changeColor();
});
     
// bgColor =  counter >= 1 ? "#14C38E" : (counter < 0 ? "#E95454" : "#2A2252");

function  changeColor(){
    if (counter > 0)
    bgColor = "#14C38E";
    else if (counter < 0)
    bgColor = "#E95454";
    else
    bgColor = "#2A2252";

}
```

Comment: `bgColor` is a variable, not a reference.

Comment: bgColor is NOT a reference to the property it is just the value at that moment in time you read it. You need to set the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the background property of the `div`, update your function as follow:

```
function  changeColor(){
    if (counter > 0)
        bgColor = "#14C38E";
    else if (counter < 0)
        bgColor = "#E95454";
    else
        bgColor = "#2A2252";

    counterWrapper.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
```

Comment: Yeah this works. Thanks. I was trying to assign bgColor to the property so I can just call the variable instead of using counterWrapper.style.backgroundColor many times.

Comment: @Ahmed please mark the answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that bgColor is considered as a string not an object. to get the result you want you have to change bgColor to

```
let bgColor = counterWrapper.style;

function  changeColor(){
if (counter > 0)
    bgColor.backgroundColor = "#14C38E";
    else if (counter < 0)
    bgColor.backgroundColor = "#E95454";
    else
    bgColor.backgroundColor = "#2A2252";
}
```

Comment: I didn't to repeat the property thats what I was avoiding it . Thanks for the effort.